# Intuitive model to show difference between photon energy and light intensity?

Tags: soft-question, photons, education

What would be a good (intuitive, easily comprehensible) model to explain the quantum nature of light insofar as there is a fundamental difference between intensity and photon energy?

One example (not model) would be the fact that intense IR light donesn't harm the skin (think of heat lamps) whereas small amounts of UV light can cause sunburn or skin cancer.

My best idea so far is the difference of sand vs. stones falling on one's skin from a certain height. Sand doesn't hurt, no matter how much sand hits you, but individual stones can hurt.

I'm sure there are better models.

I'm trying to target audiences with basic physical education.

Comment: My first thought was massage device vs. chainsaw. Probably not the best though :D

Comment: This is interesting, but seems possibly *too broad* or *opinion based.* It would really fit well with [Science Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79366/science-educators?referrer=5P7ZGrVh-vnMRAWyY3pk8g2) if it ever gets off the ground.

Comment: Thanks @BMS for pointing out that site, didn't know about it. Should I add it as an example question there? I don't think that this question is 'too broad', because it is about a specific physical fact. 'opinion based': maybe.